# How do I block all IP addresses from connecting remotely to Cassandra?

Tags: docker, cassandra, ip, remote-access

I want access to remote cassandra with one ip address. how can I change cassandra.yaml to block all ip address except ip that I want to connect?

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

On current Cassandra versions there's no way to block inbound connections. You can (and you must) enable authentication, but it seems that you want to block before Auth phase.